# How to correctly escape double-percent parameters, i.e. %%x to correctly show them in echo output

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, cmd

What I'm trying to do is to put a simple `echo` message on the console saying:

```
variable named %%x has value of 'this is text inside the variable
```

so command I must do must escape the percentages that belong to variable name so it doesn't evaluate. Normally the escape character for `%` is another `%`. So this works:

```
echo %%variable%% has value: %variable%
```

But this doesn't, seems that double percent variables used in `for` loops always evaluate:

```
echo %%%%x has value: %%x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a silly hack that seems to work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set percent=%%
for %%a in (*) do (
    echo !percent!!percent!a is %%a
)
```

Or you can do `set dblpercent=%%%%` and `echo !dblpercent!a`...